# Set options globally with Knockout Kendo

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

Following http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/AutoComplete.html I thought it would be a good idea to set many options globally. So I also tried

```
<input data-bind="kendoAutoComplete: {}" />

ko.bindingHandlers.kendoAutoComplete.options.data = "choices";
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoAutoComplete.options.value = "selectedChoice";
```

However, it does not work. The input element is made into an AutoComplete, but no elements show up when typing.

Are there some options that must be set in the markup? Or do I make some mistake and should all options be allowed in the global object?

Comment: Can we see the ViewModel ?

Comment: The view model is unchanged. It is the same as in the mentioned url. The idea is to remove all information from the html markup and put it into the Javascript code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

I misunderstood the options object. I thought that I could define the names of the viewmodel properties there. I now realized that I have to code the actual values instead.

I would have prefered if I would be able to globally define "*the data is always read from the 'data' property of the view model*". However, this is not the intended use case for the global options.